# Physics used in gravity of falling and jumping objects in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, game-physics

I am trying to make a flappy bird clone and I can't seem to get the physics right. I'm not great at physics and everytime I try numbers, it always seems to choppy and not like the original. Right now I have a fall and jump increment that is changed each time by multiplying it by a constant to make it fall faster and get slower as it jumps, but it doesn't look right.
Is there another way to do the physics of jumping?

**EDIT** I can't add the rest of the code since that doesn't relate to the problem, so this code will not run without cetain module variables in the rest of my code.

Here is my bird class

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self,root,canvas,x=150,y=300,size=40):
        global jumped
        #Sets attributes
        self.size=size
        self.faller=True
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.root=root
        self.fell=4 #The initial amount to fall
        jingle=13 #The initial amount to jump
        self.canvas=canvas
        #sets the image
        im=PhotoImage(file="unnamed copy 2.gif")
        self.photo=im
        self.current=self.canvas.create_image((self.x,self.y),image=self.photo)
    def fall(self): #Always runs in the background, if the user isn't jumping, to fall
        global done,t,points,j,height
        if self.faller and not done: 
            self.y+=self.fell
            self.fell*=t    #Falls and multiplies how much it fell by the exponential constant
            if self.y+(height/2)>=600:  # if it hit the ground, it ends the game
                done=True
                self.fall()  #Runs the method again to execute the code when done is True
                return

            self.canvas.coords(self.current,(self.x,self.y))
            self.canvas.after(20,self.fall) #Runs it again after 20 milliseconds
        elif done and self.faller:
            self.faller=False  #Stops the falling
            end()


    def jump(self,e):
        global done,j,jingle,orange,t
        if not done and orange: #If it isnt dead and it has been a
                                #sufficient time since the user last jumped
            self.faller=False   #Stops the falling
            x=1
            while x<=10:
                if not done:
                    for item in pipes: #Checks if it has hit each time it goes up
                        if item.hit(self): # if it has, it stops and dies
                            done=True
                            return
                self.canvas.after(12*x,self.move) # it moves up a little, 10 times
                x+=1
            self.faller=True #After it is done, it lets itself fall again
            self.fell=4  #Sets the amount it falls back to the default
            jingle=13 #Sets the amount it jumps back to default
            orange=False #Stops the user from jumping really fast, like holding space
            j=.97 #Sets the exponential constants back to normal
            t=1.09
            self.canvas.after(100,self.toll) #After 100 ms, it lets the user jump again
    def toll(self): #sets the boolean that stops jumping back to True
        global orange
        orange=True
    def move(self): #Moves and multiplies how much it moves by the constant
        global jingle,j
        self.y-=jingle
        jingle*=j
        self.canvas.coords(self.current,(self.x,self.y))
    def changey(self,a): #A method to change the user's position
        self.y=a
        self.canvas.coords(self.current,(self.x,self.y))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a physics question than a programming question, but:

For the physics to be realistic, you need to keep track of the bird's position (`self.x` and `self.y`), velocity (`self.vx` and `self.vy`), and acceleration (`self.ax` and `self.ay`).

`self.ay` should be set to a constant which determines how fast you want objects to fall.

`self.ax` should typically be `0.0`.

In the run loop, this needs to happen:

```
self.x += self.vx * t
self.y += self.vy * t

self.vx += self.ax * t
self.vy += self.ay * t
```

Comment: what is 't' in this example?

Comment: `t` is a variable denoting time.  It should increment by some amount in each run loop.